# Validating a textbox is between two numbers

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a series of 15 TextBox controls on my WinForms application. Each named `txtValue1`, `txtValue2`, ... , `txtValue15`

[image]

What I would like to do is to make sure that value of a textbox, when changed and the user loses focus on the field (`.Leave` event is raised), to compare the value is numerical lower than its successor field but higher than its predecessor field (where available).

(There is already a Sub procedure in place to make sure that only numbers are entered in them and that extra zeroes are trimmed off from the front..)

I previously used a code from another answer I obtained from stackExchange but wondered what I would need to change to make this a comparison instead?

```
For i As Integer = trkNoOfQuestions.Value To 1 Step -1
        ' The question value
        Dim txts = Me.Controls.Find("txtQuestionValue" & i.ToString, True)
        If txts.Count > 0 Then
            Dim txt As TextBox = txts.First
            txt.Enabled = True
        End If
Next
```

Comment: You just get the `txt.Value` for `"txtQuestionValue" & (i - 1).ToString` and `i+1` (check if they exist first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but has some limitations:
- if you enter 1,2,3,4,5 and then decide to overtype with 1,5, you'll get stuck here because 5 is greater than 3. So you would have to retype starting biggest going to smallest.
- you may need to do some extra footwork depending on how you intend to handle 0s.

```
 Private Sub txtValue1_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtValue1.Validating,
        txtValue2.Validating, txtValue3.Validating, txtValue4.Validating, txtValue5.Validating

        Try

            For counter As Integer = 1 To 5 
                Dim txtThis() = Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("txtValue", counter), True)
                Dim txtPrevious() = Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("txtValue", counter - 1), True)
                Dim txtNext() = Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("txtValue", counter + 1), True)
                'compare this textbox to the previous
                If txtThis.Length > 0 AndAlso txtPrevious.Length > 0 Then
                    Dim thisValue As Integer
                    Dim previousValue As Integer
                    Integer.TryParse(txtPrevious(0).Text, previousValue)
                    Integer.TryParse(txtThis(0).Text, thisValue)

                    If thisValue <= previousValue Then
                        If thisValue > 0 AndAlso previousValue > 0 Then

                            e.Cancel = True
                            'show alert
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                If txtThis.Length > 0 AndAlso txtNext.Length > 0 Then
                    Dim thisValue As Integer
                    Dim nextValue As Integer
                    Integer.TryParse(txtNext(0).Text, nextValue)
                    Integer.TryParse(txtThis(0).Text, thisValue)

                    If thisValue > nextValue Then
                        If thisValue > 0 AndAlso nextValue > 0 Then
                            e.Cancel = True
                            'show alert
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If


            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: So far it seems to work but it treats 0's weird and blanks it out... I think that came from my code since it trims off zeroes and returns a blank box. Generally a person shouldn't be able to enter a zero